# Exact Proportion definition , need help

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Proportion means that we have an equal ratios,
$$\frac {a}{b}=\frac {c}{d}$$

My question: Is there any condition about the numbers $a , b , c , d$ to be only positive? i.e., can they be negative numbers, I need the right definition about proportion.

Thanks!

Comment: Usually the terms are assumed positive, but the "right definition" might depend on context and allow negative numbers. After all, $-2$ is twice $-1$.

Comment: According to M.L.Aggarwal and his seventh standard math textbook, this notion is allowed only when $a,b,c,d$ are positive numbers. Otherwise, the equation $\frac ab = \frac cd$ holds no restrictions other than $b,d\neq 0$.